# Help With Ruby FFI

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am simply trying to make a few basic Windows calls to print the information from a MIDI input device (keyboard). The calls seem to work, but the first two calls to midiInOpen and midiInStart return `MMSYSERR_NOMEM` and `MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE`. I believe it has something to do with `ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:pointer)` but I don't know enough about FFI to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
require 'ffi'

module MIDI; end

module MIDI::Input
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'winmm'
  ffi_convention :stdcall

  callback :midiInProc, [ :pointer, :uint, :int, :int, :int  ], :void

  attach_function :midiInOpen, [ :pointer, :uint, :midiInProc, :int, :int ], :int
  attach_function :midiInClose, [ :long ], :int

  attach_function :midiInStart, [ :long ], :int
  attach_function :midiInStop, [ :long ], :int
  attach_function :midiInReset, [ :long ], :int

  MidiInProcCallback = Proc.new do |hmidiin, wmsg, dwintance, dwparam1, dwparam2|
    p hmidiin, wmsg, dwintance, dwparam1, dwparam2
  end
end

require 'pp'
ptr = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:pointer)
p MIDI::Input.midiInOpen(ptr, 0, MIDI::Input::MidiInProcCallback, 0, 0)
p MIDI::Input.midiInStart(ptr.read_long)

trap("INT") do
  p MIDI::Input.midiInStart(ptr.read_long)
  p MIDI::Input.midiInClose(ptr.read_long)
  p ptr.free
  exit
end

loop {}
```

Comment: A question to Ryan: I have the same problem here. The result of midiInOpen is MMSYSERR_NOERROR and the Callback Function is called excactly one time, after midiInOpen. Then I call midiInStart and the result is MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE. Did you find out, what the problem is or what are the correct flags to set in midiInOpen, that the error disappears?

Answer (score 1):

No definite answer, as your code looks mostly correct, but I suspect it is the dwFlags (the last param) you are passing to midiInOpen() that is the problem.  Looking at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798458(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it seems that it needs to be non-zero.

Try looking in the winmm header file for the value of CALLBACK_FUNCTION, and declare a similar constant in your module, then use it as the flags param.

There is a C# wrapper at http://powersdr-iq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/Console/midi.cs that might be useful example of someone else wrapping the same API using the C# P/Invoke interface.

Your signatures for midiInOpen and the callback are slightly wrong (but won't be causing this problem).  They should be:

```
callback :midiInProc, [ :pointer, :uint, :pointer, :pointer, :pointer  ], :void

attach_function :midiInOpen, [ :pointer, :uint, :midiInProc, :pointer, :int ], :int
```

i.e. use :pointer where the API docs use DWORD_PTR

Comment: this seems to have stopped the `MMSYSERR_NOMEM` and `MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE` errors. The callback function doe not seem to be working though.

Comment: Do you need to pump the windows message loop, as shown in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/arirusso/midi-winmm/blob/master/lib/midi-winmm/map.rb

Oh! That is some of yours. Cool. It works.

I know this works in windows because I've tried it out. My biggest desire is to find the documentation from Microsoft for the winmm.dll api. which I think that I have found thanks to your question being answered by user186057.

Thanks.